# Context loader control with Phased interface in Spring

Tags: spring

I am trying to take under control the context loading process. As I can read in Spring reference documentation I determined to use Phased interface provided by Spring.

> When starting, the objects with the lowest phase start first, and when
>   stopping, the reverse order is followed. Therefore, an object that
>   implements SmartLifecycle and whose getPhase() method returns
>   Integer.MIN_VALUE would be among the first to start and the last to
>   stop. At the other end of the spectrum, a phase value of
>   Integer.MAX_VALUE would indicate that the object should be started
>   last and stopped first (likely because it depends on other processes
>   to be running). When considering the phase value, it’s also important
>   to know that the default phase for any "normal" Lifecycle object that
>   does not implement SmartLifecycle would be 0. Therefore, any negative
>   phase value would indicate that an object should start before those
>   standard components (and stop after them), and vice versa for any
>   positive phase value.

```
public interface Phased {
    int getPhase();
}

public interface SmartLifecycle extends Lifecycle, Phased {
    boolean isAutoStartup();
    void stop(Runnable callback);
}
```

Only I want load two controllers in phased after all others have been initialized.

To achieve this behaviour I have implemented the Phased Interface in both Spring Components.

@Service to be initialized at firstly.

```
@Service
public class BatchTaskController implements Phased{

    @Autowired
    private ActorService actorService;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public BatchTaskController(){

        this.batch();
    }

    public void batch(){

        //TO DO...
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {

        return 1;
    }
```

}

@Controller to be initialized after batch task @Service.

```
 @Controller
    public class MainController implements Phased{

        @Autowired
        private ActorService actorService;
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"})
        public String showHome(HttpServletRequest request) {

            //TO DO

            return "index";
        }

        @Override
        public int getPhase() {

            return 2;
        }   

    }
```

ActorService @Service not implement Phased Interface. Therefore I guess as I could read in the Spring Reference article exposed above that ActorService @Service is starting before than previous @Controllers because ActorService @Service phase valor was 0 by default.

But, when I deploy my app i get the next NullPointerException error.

```
04-04-2014 08:34:10,286 AM ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchTaskController' defined in file [E:\Desarrollo\Spring\pjcomspringehcache\target\pjcomspringehcache-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\pjcom\pjcomspringehcache\BatchTaskController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.pjcom.pjcomspringehcache.BatchTaskController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5158)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1744)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.uti
l.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.pjcom.pjcomspringehcache.BatchTaskController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pjcom.pjcomspringehcache.BatchTaskController.batch(BatchTaskController.java:32)
    at com.pjcom.pjcomspringehcache.BatchTaskController.<init>(BatchTaskController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 28 more
```

Why?

**SOLUTION**

@Service to be initialized at firstly.

```
@Service
public class BatchTaskController implements Phased{

    @Autowired
    private ActorService actorService;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @PostConstruct    
    public void batch(){

        //TO DO...
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {

        return 1;
    }
```

}

Comment: There is a `NullPointerException` in your own code, you should show it here or explain how it's related to this. Besides, I am not sure I understand the point of having a `@Controller` implementing `Phased`. Are you trying to delay the availability of the http endpoint or something? Because that's not what that does.

Comment: NullPointerException is because ActorService @Service autowired in BatchTaskController is null when the constructor is invoked and I try to use it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that you implement `Phased`. You can't use a wired field in the constructor simply because such fields are initialized once the object has been created (i.e. **after** the constructor call). You may want to autowire the constructor instead.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to delay the execution of some batch task after your beans are created. You could definitely use `@PostConstruct` or even `@Scheduled` if you just want to control when this method will be called.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was confused with the @PostConstruct behaviour. Now it works fine. :)